# Sharing class objects in Tensorlfow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

`TF` has `tf.variable_scope()` that allows users to access `tf.Variable()` anywhere in the code. Basically every variable in `TF` is a global variable.

Is there a similar way to access class objects like `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell()` or `tf.layers.Dense()`? To be more specific, can i create a new class object, let's say `lstm_cell_2` (used for prediction) that uses the same weights and biases in `lstm_cell_1` (used during training).

I am building an RNN to do language modeling. What i am doing right now is to return the `lstm_cell_1` then pass it onto the prediction function. This works, but i want to in the end use separate `tf.Graph()` and `tf.Session()` for training, inference and prediction. Hence comes the problem of sharing Tensorflow objects.

Also, my `lstm_cell` is an instance of `tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell()` which doesn't take a name argument.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can share final state that is one of the outputs of for example consider dynamic rnn. You get `outputs,cell_final_state` which you can share. You probably know about `cell_final_state.c` and `cell_final_state.h`. you can set that final state as initial state. lemme know if I cleared your question or not.

Just noticed it's such an old question. Hopefully helps future people.